# Can I use both Thunderbolt ports to get higher resolution/framerate

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, 4k

I have a mid-2014 Macbook Pro (Iris Pro 1536) with an AOC U2790B. It can only run 4k at very low framerate so I downscale it.

I seem to recall reading a long time ago about using both Thunderbolt ports at once to drive a single monitor. Is that possible with my setup?

Comment: EveryMac seems to think this is not an option: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.6-13-mid-2014-retina-display-specs.html . Assuming that is the right one, the built-in GPU doesn't support high frame rates at its higher resolution. The article goes into a bit of detail in the linked 2nd display port section that does not seem to mention using two ports combined. As this model doesn't have a secondary GPU it seems unlikely that using two ports would give you better than only using one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the speed of the connection, a Thunderbolt 2 port has the bandwidth for a display size and refresh rate of at least 4K@60Hz or 5K@30Hz.  Using two Thunderbolt connections to a single display requires a display that supports this, and this is a feature that I recall was short lived as there are now cable and connector standards readily available for supporting 8K displays with refresh rates of at least 60Hz.

The problem is not a lack of bandwidth.  The problem is that the GPU in the laptop doesn't support more than 4K@30Hz.  To get better than this means adding an external GPU, or getting a new computer.

Comment: Whoa. External GPUs are a thing?

Comment: External GPUs are a thing.  Finding ones that list support for Thunderbolt 2 are rare.  Finding ones that work in spite of this is trivial.  Most any Thunderbolt 3 eGPU should work on a Thunderbolt 2 connection with nothing more than the right cable and adapter.  Keep in mind that Thunderbolt 2 has half the max data rate, no native USB on the bus, and passes only enough power to drive the adapter or cable when compared to Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like my challenge also might be finding a cheap one. Considering most of them are specced for gaming or video editing, and all I want is to drive a few more pixels. Is asking for a recommendation for one allowed here?